# Live streaming of simulation video using java websockets becomes unresponsive over time

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, glassfish

We are performing a study in which we are sending images from a simulation to an HTML web client in real time using java web sockets. We have noticed that the system becomes unresponsive ¼ of the way through the study and discovered that if we remove the

session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);

line everything runs fine except no video from the simulation. However, once we add this line back the system initially works but eventually slows/becomes unresponsive.

I do not understand why this is happening and do not know what to do about it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Below I have included a segment of the Java code that grabs the image as a binary and sends it to the client.  Currently on the client side we do nothing with the binary data accept print the size of the data.

```
//Grab a binary version of the image from the simulation.  Occurs 10 fps
protected void schedST_PostStageScreenMessage() {
    LOG.log(Level.FINEST, "schedST_PostStageScreenMessage()");

    //if(getCurrentDisplayMode() == DisplayMode.FULL){
        // get the current proxy state
        ProxyState state = this._robot.getProxy().getCurrentState();
        if (state == null) {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "schedST_PostStageScreenMessage() - no state");
            return;
        }

        // get the latest received screen message from the sim proxy
        ScreenMessage screenMsg = state.msgLastScreen();
        if(screenMsg == null) {
            LOG.log(Level.FINER, "schedST_PostStageScreenMessage() - no update");
            return;
        }

        // check to see if it has been updated since last time
        if(this._screenMsg == screenMsg) {
            LOG.log(Level.FINEST, "schedST_PostStageScreenMessage() - no screen message update");
            return;
        }

        this._screenMsg = screenMsg;
        ScreenResponse sr = (ScreenResponse)createSceneMessage();
        doPost(sr.getPngData());
        //doPost(createSceneMessage());
    //}

}

private void doPost(byte[] message){
    try {
        postMessage(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught: " + e, e);
    }
}

 protected void postMessage(byte[] message) {
                WebSocketEndpointERA.sendToAll(message);
            }

public static void sendToAll(final byte[] data){
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    System.out.println("Sending bytes of length: " + data.length);
    Set<Session> sessions = getSessions();
    try{
        for (Session session : sessions) {
            //When this line is commented out the system works
            //However when we send the binary image the system works initially
            //and then becomes unresponsive
            session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);


        }
    }catch(IOException io){
         LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to send binary message: {0}", io);
    }
    buf = null;
}
```

And on the Javascript side we have the following temporarily in place for testing

```
function onMessage(event) {
    //console.log('Received a message!');
    if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        //handleBinaryEventMessage(event.data);
        //Do nothing with the binary data right now
        return;
    }

    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    //writeToMessages("Received message: " + msg.type);
    switch (msg.type) {
        case 'RobotPoseResponse':
            handleRobotPoseMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'RobotAcousticResponse':
            handleRobotSensorDataMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'RobotGoalResponse':
            handleRobotGoalMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'AvailableQuestionsResponse':
            handleOptionsEventMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'ExplanationResponse':
            handleExplanationMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'ScenarioResponse':
            handleScenarioMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'ScreenResponse':
            handleScreenMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'SceneResponse':
            handleSceneMessage(msg);
            break;
        case 'StageStartUpResponse':
            handleStageStartUp(msg);
            break;
        default:
            writeToEvents("Received unhandled message: " + msg.type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I have answered my own question. We switched the Websockets from synchronous to asynchronous and that appears to have resolved the issue on our Mac.  For some reason asynchronous does not work when tested on Ubunutu.  I am not clear on why switching from synchronous to asynchronous resolves this situation.

In the code we switched the following

from

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);
```

to

```
session.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(buf);
```

Thanks